# Conditional vs Logical Testing

Tags: conditions, vba, logical-operator

I would like to get your code thought and views on using conditional vs logical testing.

**For example:**

To test the conditions of truthness of all of the following variables, their currect status is as follows:

```
a= True

b= True

c= True

d= True

e= True
```

One could use as test as follows to ensure that **they all are true**:

1. Method 1:

```
If a And b And c And d And e Then x = "Passed" Else x = "Failed"
```

2. Metod 2:

```
If a = b = c = d = e Then x = "Passed" Else x = "Failed"
```

3. Method 3:

```
If a Then If b Then If c Then If d Then If e Then x = "Passed" Else x = "Failed"
```

With all variables being "True": Method 2 is the slowest and Method 3 using Condition is fastest.

If any of the variables states would be changed from True to False then Method 3 (Conditional) always wins by big margin.

I do tend to test 2 conditions or more for truthness using the AND logic (we all do, i guess). But isn't quicker to do an "If If" statement.

Looking forward to your valuable feedback and input.

kind regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> If a Then If b Then If c Then If d Then If e Then x = "Passed" Else x = "Failed"
> ```

That is some horrendous code right there, and it doesn't do what you think it does either: the 3 "methods" you're showing are NOT equivalent. If we expand #3...

```
If a Then
    If b Then
        If c Then
            If d Then
                If e Then
                    x = "Passed"
                Else
                    x = "Failed"
                End If
            End If
         End If
     End If
 End If
```

...we see much more clearly that the only way to get `x = "Failed"` is to have all but `e` be `True` - `x` remains unassigned in every single other case.

It doesn't matter which method is the fastest, if the fastest method doesn't work as it should.

In fact, it doesn't matter which method is the fastest, if reading that code is deceptive and *looks* like it should do something, but when you actually stop and read what's going on, you realize it's doing something else.

Write code that's *correct* first. Then make that code *obviously correct*. **Then** make it more efficient ***if*** it needs to be made more efficient: the vast majority of the time, if your code has a performance bottleneck, it's not going to be in places like this.

"Method 2" will wrongly output "Passed" if `a` and `b` are both `False` and everything else is `True`.

"Method 1" is the only code you've got that will consistently output "Passed" when all conditions are true, and "Failed" when one of the conditions is false.

Don't try to write clever code. Write code that works, and then refactor as needed.

What's [slightly] inefficient about #1 is that it evaluates all conditions, even if `a` is `False` - in languages such as C# or Java, the condition would "short-circuit" and the rest of the expression wouldn't be evaluated. In VB.NET, the `AndAlso` short-circuiting operator would do the same.

If profiling code execution reveals that evaluating these conditionals *is* a performance bottleneck, then the first step is to take #1 and nest the conditions.

```
x = "Failed"
If a Then
    If b Then
        If c Then
            If d Then
                If e Then
                    x = "Passed"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
 End If
```

Now we still get correct results, and only evaluate all conditions if we have to. Problem is, that's *arrow code*, and it's annoyingly ugly.

So what we do is, we write a function whose role is abstract away the iteration a bunch of conditions, and bail out as soon as one of them is `False`:

```
Public Function All(ParamArray values() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        If Not CBool(values(i)) Then Exit Function
    Next
    All = True
End Function
```

And now we get performant short-circuiting logic* *and* readability:

```
x = IIf(All(a, b, c, d, e), "Passed", "Failed")
```

* Assuming `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` are all *values* and not *expressions*. Expressions would all have to be evaluated in order for their results to be passed as arguments to the function.

Comment: how will Method 2 work if it is in brackets i.e. if (a=b=c=d=e). Will the condition work?

Comment: Exactly the same. Expressions are evaluated left-to-right, so `a=b` first, then take the result of that, compare to `c`; take the result of that, compare to `d`; take the result of that, compare to `e`. Surrounding the expression in parentheses makes no difference.

Comment: We should elemenate Metod 2 as unsuitable. Left with Metod 1 or 3 (Conditional or Logical)

Comment: There is no distinction between what you call "logical" and "conditional". `If foo` is equivalent to `If foo = True`.

Comment: I found that method 3 using If on 2 conditions is faster. Do you agree?. e.g. (If A And B) vs ( If A If B)

Comment: This discussion is pointless, as thoroughly explained in this answer... "Method 3" is incorrect and confusing. Don't do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95876/discussion-between-mohsen-alyafei-and-mathieu-guindon).

Comment: Write code that expresses your intent first. Correct first is simply fantasy and even if achieved the world will change until correct is wrong.  Show me your intent and when I show up later I'll be able to figure out what to do.

Comment: @candied_orange fair enough. Code that correctly expresses intent is likely correct though ;-)

Comment: Ive been coding long enough that hearing someone say "this code is likely correct" feels like watching someone stare into the infinite universe  while they say, "oh I've seen all that before".

Comment: @candied_orange no need to stare into the void of the universe, the point was *first get it to work as intended, THEN worry about whether it's more efficient to write it this way or that way*.

Answer (score 5):

I feel I must insist on readable, flexible, debugable code.

```
If a = False Then Return "Failed"
If b = False Then Return "Failed"
If c = False Then Return "Failed"
If d = False Then Return "Failed"
Return "Passed"
```

Or more simply

```
Debug.Assert a
Debug.Assert b
Debug.Assert c
Debug.Assert d
```

Please do not couple together separate ideas needlessly. Please do not punish me with needless indentation. Please do not push forms beyond their readable limits simply because they were readable when they had fewer ideas in them.

There is no structure so correct that it  won't require restructuring if you push it beyond its readable limits. In fact, improving readability is the best reason to restructure.

Comment: You know what, you're absolutely right. KISS wins all the time! (see edit on my answer)

Comment: I'm working with a library that has lots of assertions like assert (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) instead of having three asserts, so when the assert failed I can then start chasing down which of the three conditions was the reason. While I wouldn't say that it is the most readable code, it is certainly the most debuggable one, which can be very important.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in following way also.

```
if(!A)
  then return "Failed";
else
  if(!B)
    then return "Failed";
```

This could increase overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

The speed and readability don't matter, because two of your three different styles give completely wrong results.

a = b = c = d = e most definitely doesn't do what you think it does.

And method 3 leaves x undefined unless a, b, c and d are all true.